# excel 2010: how to convert 2d coordinate columns to 2d coordinate per row

Tags: excel

I have a csv with *x1;y1; x2;y2; ... xn;yn* in a **single row**. What is the simplest (i.e. **non VBA**) way, to get a scatter plot (x1,y1)->(x2,y2)->... out of it?

- Idea 1) Maybe someone knows a (non VBA) way to transpose the single row into n rows just containing xi, yi?
  I know, how to transpose a selection (*Paste Special*), but here, I would need to transpose **every second** column item into a row. Can this be done without VBA? Note, that there are too many items to be selected interleaved by hand:(
- Idea 2) Maybe the *Select Data Source* dialog of the scatter plot diagram is able to do this special data selection?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that when you open the .csv in Excel, each cell in row 1 is populated such that A1 = x1, B1 = y1, C1 = x2, etc. If that is the case then you can simply:

1. Transpose the entire row into a single column. Paste the cells into A2
   and then clear row 1.
2. Apply a text filter on column A for text that contains "x" and copy
   the the filtered column into col B.
3. Remove the filter on col A and repeat step 2 with a text filter on cells containing
   "y".

Comment: Yep, that works fine, thank you - 
and if I would have 15 points, I would be allowed to up-vote your answer ;)

Comment: Good to know that helped out. Maybe when you get that 15th point then!